# How to present data in table grid?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm creating a Drupal 8 module which require to present data in table-grid manner
something similar like below:

[image]

The data will be retrieve in JSON format from REST API service (another server) - which I've done this part using

```
self::$client = \Drupal::service('http_client');`
$result = self::$client->request($method, $full_uri, $data);
$output = json_decode($result->getBody()); // <-- i manage to get my result here
//But then, how do i present the data in table-view?
```

Is there any Drupal API to present the data in Table Grid as image above??

**Note**:  I need the operations also, so not just rendering the data in a table format. These operations should be present in row, at the end column, where there should be edit (which will go to edit page) and delete (which will give confirmation dialog then delete once it's confirmed).

Comment: Do u need operations also or u just need to render data in table format

Comment: I need both, present in row, at the end column, there will be edit, which will go to edit page and delete which will give confirmation dialog then delete once it's confirmed

Comment: Yes. There has always been the table render element (theme function in previous versions). If your data is in a database or an entity, then you might consider creating a Views-module view, using an Entity list builder (if it's an entity). But at the very least you can use [table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Table.php/class/Table/8.2.x) as the value of the `#theme` property in a render element.

Comment: @mradcliffe, thanks, and yes, my content will be from rest api server (response in json format), so it's recommended to use `Views-module view` ? is there any reference/sample for this model that i can look at?

Comment: No, I was not recommending an approach because I did not know enough details. Can you update your question with the details including where the data is coming from (a restful service from json in a controller)?

Comment: @mradcliffe. i have edited my questions, please do let me know if you require more detailed information, i'll be happy to share.